# There are multiple things to be discussed regarding LEDs and KVL

Tags: voltage, led, diodes, series, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcenvN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have 3 Red LEDs and a 3 volt cr2032 coin cell. All the LEDs are in series with the cell. Obviously, none works as the combined forward voltage is more than supply voltage. But voltage across each LED is 0.12 volt, but it should be around 1 volt. The main problem is with sum of the voltages; the supply voltage is showing 2.88 volts on multimeter whereas adding the voltage across each led gives me only 0.36 volts. Where is the rest of the voltage? since Total voltage = V1 + V2 +V3. Is there any theory behind it? The same problem occurs with LEDs of different forward voltages with the same cell. For example, white in series with red.

I think that when these LEDs are in series there is a small current flowing through the circuit. And according to its V-I curve, for that small current, LED gets a particular voltage across it. Because when only 2 LEDs of same forward voltage (same colour) are in series they satisfy V=V1 +V2. Please help with this one and thanks already.

Comment: How did you measure it? Draw a circuit diagram.

Comment: If each LED is off, acting as a resistor of about 100 Megohms, then there will be 1V across each. However when you measure that voltage with a 10 Megohm DMM, you will only see about 0.1V. Also, that voltage reduction puts more voltage across the others, bringing them closer to conduction, reducing their resistance.

Comment: The circuit diagram is there and i measured with a DMM in parallel to each led as shown. @Brian but with only 2 leds i get 1.45 V across each LED. But why this changes with 3 LEDs in series?

Comment: "the supply voltage is showing 2.88 volts [...] whereas adding the voltage across each led gives me only 0.36 volts": with the schematic you shown, those two statements *cannot* both be true. Impossible. You're taking the measurements wrong. What you expected, on the other hand (having ~1V across each led) follows correct logic (provided all leds have the same characteristics). Also, did you measure the supply voltage *with* the leds connected, or with the leds disconnected? That may make a difference.

Comment: @dim i measured the voltage across the battery with leds connected and it showed 2.88 volts. but across every led it is 0.12 volt. The battery shows almost the same voltage with or without the LEDs

Comment: I maintain this is impossible. Maybe one of the led is 0.12V, but there must be one >1V, then (they may have varying characteristics). Measure all leds, make sure the schematics is really the one you shown us, and that you're taking all measurements correctly.

Comment: @dim I have been working on this since a month and couldn't find a solution and hence i posted it here. I was also boggled on seeing this, but my friend it is true. You can check it yourself and do it with a battery not a DC power supply. And yes every led shows 0.12 Volt

Comment: @dim totally possible. The meter impedance is loading the remaining LEDs. Now if he used three meters to measure the three LED voltages **at the same time** and the readings differed, **that** would be impossible (give or take small reading errors).

Comment: @Neil_UK Wow. Indeed, I didn't imagine the meter was modifying the measurements. That is probably the answer, then. I also just realize that was initially the suggestion from Brian, above. Sorry, guys.

Comment: @Neil_UK you mean to say that I should try to measure the voltage across each led simultaneously with 3 DMM and then I'll get that 1 volt

Comment: Please model your circuit where each LED is an ideal LED with forward voltage drop and a 10 Meg resistor in paralell to represent the leakage. Model your multimeter as a 1 Meg resistor. Now apply your normal voltage division rules and calculate the voltage in each node.

Comment: Alternative to three DMMs : solder 1 Megohm across each LED. Then 10 Meg from one DMM will make very little difference. Your observation with only 2 LEDs is consistent : 1.45V across a red LED causes enough conduction (maybe a few microamps) that 10 Meg makes little difference.

Comment: will i get a different reading with an analog voltmeter?

Comment: @BrianDrummond as i understand, when i have 3 LEDs the current flowing through them is obviously less than the 2 LEDs in series. And in 2 LEDs in series, the LEDs are almost near conduction as 1.6V is the fwd voltage drop and hence they have less resistance and lesser than my DMM and so i get the accurate reading. But with 3 LEDs, the LEDs are far away from conduction and hence higher resistance, can be higher than my DMM and hence the voltage that i see is because the efective resistance is now dropped and as @.winny said, i must get a DMM with high i/p impedance. Is this the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term non-conducting is misleading. Even in reverse polarity a LED's internal resistance is not infinity but still has a (very) high resistance that can be measured or found in the datasheet as I-sub-R (reverse current). Replacing the LEDs and the DMM by their resistive values it is easy calculating their parallel (LED and DMM) and their serial resistances. It is a simple Voltage-divider circuit, but you should be aware that the voltage measured at each node is depending on the DMM connected parallel to it or not.

If you put DMMs parallel to each LED at the same time the sum of the voltages will add up to the input voltage. But still the measured voltages are different to those that exist without the DMMs.

E.g.: 100 MΩ parallel 10 MΩ = ~9 MΩ. 100 MΩ || 100 MΩ = 50 MΩ

If the DMMs internal resistance is not substantially higher than the internal resistance of the subject to be measured then the result is rather far away from reality.

Comment: But the sum of the voltages across each led does not equals the battery voltage. why?

Comment: Because every time you measure the voltage across another LED the Voltage indicated is influenced by the DMM parallel to it. In order to learn the real voltages across each LED you have to include the internal resistance of the DMM into your calculation.

Comment: so if i put 3 DMM simultaneously across every led, i should get the desired reading. and also why the same thing does not happen with only 2 LEDs in series?

Comment: So, i got 3 DMMs and did it. Yes, i got 1 volt across each led. But couldn't understand why the same thing doesn't happens with 2 LEDs. Even with 1 DMM i get 1.47 V and it goes upto 1.5 V when 2 DMMs are used

Comment: @U.sir Yes. But at that point you can remove the LEDs as well since you are only measuring the voltage distribution between the multimeters, not the LEDs. You need a multimeter with even higher imput impedance.

Comment: @winny so if i put 3 DMMs, i'll be measuring voltage across DMM and not the LEDs.

Comment: @U.sir In effect, yes, since your multimeters have lower impedance than the LEDs.

Comment: The voltages measured depend on the resistors relationships.

Comment: If you have information you want to add to your answer, please edit the original answer rather than creating a new one.